# Android: back button skips webView

Tags: java, android

I'm a novice developer building a live wallpaper.  I have a settings screen that can open a webview to browse my web page, which has links to various video files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

This is controlled by:

```
    public class intMarket extends Activity {
        public static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME="videowallpapersettings";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.intbrowser);

            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

            String tUrl = getString(R.string.urlMarket);
            myWebView.loadUrl(tUrl);
        }

        public class  WebAppInterface {
            Context mContext;

            /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
            WebAppInterface(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
            }

            /** previewVideo(pUrl) - Downloads a video from a url and plays it in the app. */
            @JavascriptInterface
            public void previewVideo(String pUrl) {
                final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(intMarket.this);
                downloadTask.execute(pUrl);
            }
        }
    }


    // usually, subclasses of AsyncTask are declared inside the activity class.
    // that way, you can easily modify the UI thread from here
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        private Context context;
        private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

        public DownloadTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            ...
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null)
                Toast.makeText(context,"Download error: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else {
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                String rootDirectoryName = getString(R.string.rootDirectoryName);
                File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + rootDirectoryName + "/Previews");
                String path = directory + "/preview.mp4";

                setContentView(R.layout.videopreview);
                VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
                myVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
                myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getBaseContext()));
                myVideoView.requestFocus();
                myVideoView.start();
            }
        }
    }
```

When the user clicks on a thumbnail, this triggers another layout which downloads and plays the video:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Everything works perfectly fine.  The web page appears after the user clicks the settings button.  When a user clicks on a link it downloads a preview video and hops over to the video player.  However, when the user then uses the back button they are taken all the way back to the settings pane.  This is the way it ends up working:

```
 settings > browser > video > [back] > settings
```

This is how I expect it to work:

```
 settings > browser > video > [back] > browser
```

Why is the browser skipped over by the back button?

Comment: Back button goes to the last activity in stack. just handle it in onBackPressed() of the activity

Answer (score 0):

"If" I understood your question you could try adding an `onKeyDown()` for your webview as below:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```